# How to debug a std::bad_cast exception

Tags: c++, debugging

```cpp
class GAGenome {
  virtual void method(){};
};

template <class T>
class GAArray {
};

template <class T>
class GA1DArrayGenome : public GAArray<T>, public GAGenome {
};

int main() {
  GA1DArrayGenome<float> genome;
  const GAGenome & reference = genome;
  auto cast = dynamic_cast<const GA1DArrayGenome<int> &>(reference);
}
```

This obviously wrong program (since template parameter is different)  crashes with

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there a way how to get precise diagnostics of what went wrong, beyond the runtime error message? Something, that can point out the int/float mistake to me? I am looking for a descriptive error message like

> `const GA1DArrayGenome<float> &` cannot be cast to `const GA1DArrayGenome<int> &`

Even better, since C++ types can get hairy at times, the tool could notice the precise discrepancy in the template parameter.

Comment: It's an unfortunate side-effect of the `std` exceptions: by trying to avoid memory allocation their messages is almost useless, and being that they do not have a stack trace it's nigh impossible to know where they came from a posteriori. On the other hand, they are lightweight...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also abandon direct uses of `dynamic_cast` and wrap it in your own template machinery:

```
#include <sstream>

class my_bad_cast: public std::bad_cast {
public:
    my_bad_cast(char const* s, char const* d): _source(s), _destination(d) {
#ifdef WITH_BETTER_WHAT
        try {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "Could not cast '" << _source
                << "' into '" << _destination << "'";
            _what = oss.str();
        } catch (...) {
            _what.clear();
        }
#endif
    }

    char const* source() const { return _source; }
    char const* destination() const { return _destination; }

#ifdef WITH_BETTER_WHAT
    virtual char const* what() const noexcept {
        return not _what.empty() ? _what.c_str() : std::bad_cast::what();
    }
#endif

private:
    char const* _source;
    char const* _destination;
#ifdef WITH_BETTER_WHAT
    std::string _what;
#endif
    // you can even add a stack trace
};

template <typename D, typename S>
D my_dynamic_cast(S&& s) {
    try {
        return dynamic_cast<D>(std::forward<S>(s));
    } catch(std::bad_cast const&) {
        throw my_bad_cast(typeid(S).name(), typeid(D).name());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can load your program (compiled with debug information, e.g. `-g` in gcc and glang) in gbd, tell gdb to catch exceptions with `catch throw` and then look at the call stack to see exactly where the exception was thrown.

`std::bad_cast` is thrown when a `dynamic_cast` fails at runtime.

Comment: But that does not tell me what went wrong... On the other hand, I guess that a wrong type being specified is the only thing that can possibly go wrong there, right?

Comment: @user7610: yes it is, unfortunately it can come from anywhere that uses a `dynamic_cast` so in a large program it can be tough to spot...

Comment: Continuing with the example from question I can use `std::cout << typeid(reference).name();` to get the runtime type. It prints `15GA1DArrayGenomeIfE`. Is there a way how to print the template parameter as well?

Comment: @user7610 The usual use case for `dynamic_cast` is to safely cast downwards in an inheritance hierarchy. All(?, not sure) other casts like a cast between different instances of a template can be checked at compile time with more precise error messages if you do not use `dynamic_cast`for it. So if this exception is thrown unexpectedly, there is most likely something wrong with your high level program logic, something a computer can hardly diagnose correctly.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I have it. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html . The typeid().name() can be just demangled with the functions the platform c++ library provides and the template parameters are right there. Now if only I could do it without recompiling right from GDB after it breaks on the exception.

Comment: @user7610: Note that `std::type_info::name()` is implementation dependent. It so happens that on gcc it *usually* is the mangled name, however this is not a portable assumption (though it helps a lot when it works).